negate match in RE2 syntax for word at end of the string?
I want to create a RE2 regex that should not match the string if it ends with an specific word. Lets say the word health as example
was able to get a regex that could almost do this.
^([^h]|h(h|e(h|a(h|lh)))*([^eh]|e([^ah]|a([^hl]|l([^ht]|t[^h])))))*(h(h|e(h|a(h|lh)))*(e(a?|alt?))?)?$

but this one will check for word health in any place of the string.
I want the negative match only when the string ends with this word.
Is this achievable with RE2?

Strings that are shorter than the word, or
^.{0,5}$|

strings that end with a non-matching last character, or
[^h]$|

strings that end with a non-matching second-to-last character, or
[^t]h$|

⋮
(?s)^.{0,5}$|(?:[^h]ealth|[^e]alth|[^a]lth|[^l]th|[^t]h|[^h])$

(You can match a fixed number of wildcard characters after the mismatch instead of a specific suffix, e.g. ealth → .{5}.)
